# What does $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2][x]$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What does $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2][x]$ mean?

I know this has something to do with split fields, but what does this notation mean?

Answer (score 3):

It means the ring of polynomials with coeffiencients in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: Alternatively, the ring of polynomials in the two variables $\sqrt 2$ and $x$, remembering that $(\sqrt 2)^2 = 2$, and coefficients in $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Yeah, not good to call those "polynomials," just to avoid the error of confusing polynomials with polynomial functions. You could rephrase your comment, however, as $\mathbb Q[x,y]/\left<y^2-2\right>$ . @Arthur